# How can I make vinyl-source-stream output to my destination directory?

Tags: javascript, gulp, browserify

I am moving from the (working, but deprecated) `gulp-browserify` to the plain `browserify` module. My source tree looks like this:

```
projectdir
  public
    js
      src
      dist
```

My gulp task looks like the following:

```
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');

gulp.task('js', ['clean'], function() {
    // Browserify/bundle the JS.
    bundler.bundle()
        // log errors if they happen
        .on('error', function(err) {
            return notify().write(err);
        })
        .pipe(source('./public/js/src/index.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/js/dist'));

});
```

However this writes out to `public/js/dist/public/js/src/`

which is obviously bad. However changin `gulp.dest` to read:

```
.pipe(gulp.dest('./public/js/dist'));
```

Writes outside my projects directory! ie:

```
 ~/Documents/dist/public/js/src/index.js
```

I've seen lots of gulp documentation using gulp.src, but I am not using gulp.src, I am using `vinyl-source-stream`

**How can I make vinyl-source-stream output to`public/js/dist`?**

Answer (score 4):

Ended up solving this on my own:

```
var bundler = watchify(browserify({
    basedir: "./public/js/src"
}));

// Browserify our code
gulp.task('js', ['clean'], function() {
    // Browserify/bundle the JS.
    return bundler.bundle()
        // log errors if they happen
        .on('error', function(err) {
            return notify().write(err);
        })
        .pipe(source('index.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/js/dist'));
});
```

Main thing to understand is that `source` uses browserify's `basedir`, whereas `gulp.dest` does not.